# "no such file or directory" when mounting, built using the golang:alpine Docker image

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, gcsfuse

I created a [fork](https://github.com/Amitie10g/docker-transmission) of the [LinuxServer.io's docker-transmission image](https://github.com/linuxserver/docker-transmission), adding support for Google Cloud Storage.

I used the [Ernest (chiaen)'s docker-gcsfuse](https://github.com/chiaen/docker-gcsfuse) project to build gcsfuse, namely, extracting parts of his [Dockerfile](https://github.com/chiaen/docker-gcsfuse/blob/master/Dockerfile) and added to [my own one](https://github.com/Amitie10g/docker-transmission/blob/gcsfuse/Dockerfile). gcsfuse is built using the `golang:alpine` image.

The image builts successfully (including `gcsfuse`; the Dockerfile instructs to just copy gcsfuse to `/usr/local/bin`, and I checked the executable location; also, /dev/fuse is properly exposed from the host-side). However, `gcsfuse` refuses to mount, and the logs outputs `Mount: stat /donwloads: no such file or directory`, enev if the directory `/downloads` actually exists, and the right permissions were set already (set at [/etc/cont-init.d/20-config](https://github.com/Amitie10g/docker-transmission/blob/gcsfuse/root/etc/cont-init.d/20-config)). I even tried to run from the shell, but still fails.

Is there a missing package or parameter in order to get gcsfuse working in my (Alpine) Docker image?

If you want to reproduce, you may bould your own local copy of the image following the instructions at README.md in my repo (you need to upload your json key to the VM) (`amitie10g/docker-transmission` is also available at Docker Hub).

Logs are available [here](https://gist.github.com/Amitie10g/42d1b6d184827ef1d5f7059946f07621).

VM images used:

- Development: Ubuntu 18.04
- Target: Container-Optimized OS 75-12105.40.0 beta

Docker images used for building:

- lsiobase/alpine:3.9
- golang:alpine

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it `/download` or `/downloads`?

Comment: It is ``/downloads``, Wich is not exposed as volume not in the Dockerfile nor at the command line. Anyway, I tested with different names, but mounting still failing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this by building the `mount.gcsfuse` helper, and populating the `/etc/fstab` file at `/etc/cont-init.d/20.config`:

```
echo "$BUCKET /downloads gcsfuse rw,user,noauto,key_file=/config/gcsfuse-key.json" >> /etc/fstab
```

Then, running `mount.gcsfuse`:

```
s6-setuidgid abc mount.gcsfuse $BUCKET /downloads
```